# Setting upSQL Express 2014 on 2019 MS Server Core

Tags: sql-server

I cannot install by any means 32 bit version (or WOW) of SQL express 2014 on MS Server core 2016 or 2019 edition. 
 I can though install in on DE version of Windows Server.
Error message is that 32 bit version cannot be installed on Core

Comment: So what's the question?  What you wrote appears to contain the answer.

Comment: I assume SQL xpress 32bit cannot be installed on 2019core , but on 2019DE is ok. Thank you...

Answer (score 0):

- [SQL Server Hardware Requirements](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-au/sql/sql-server/install/hardware-and-software-requirements-for-installing-sql-server?view=sql-server-2014)
- [Install SQL Server 2014 on Server Core](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/install-windows/install-sql-server-on-server-core?view=sql-server-2014)

> SQL Server Express does not install .NET 4.0 on the Server Core mode of Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1 or Windows Server 2012. You must install .NET 4.0 before you install SQL Server Express on a Server Core installation of Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1 or Windows Server 2012.

You might be able to install it but it won't be as straight forward. You will have to satisfy some dependencies manually. In addition Server 2016 and Server 2019 are not officially listed as supported OS versions. As such you might find that certain features were added or removed that SQL Server relies on.

Server Core tries to minimize the system by removing unnecessary components as much as possible. Server 2016 and up removes the option to switch between DE and Core.

Comment: Already installed .Net3.5 and .Net4.7 . But no luck. So do i have to try installing .NET 4.0 ?

Comment: 4.7 should be sufficient. Going by your original question make sure that you're using a 64 bit installer. It could be that 2016 Core removed the 32 bit subsystem (I'm not sure about it).

Comment: I have to use SQL 32bit as a part of another installer. As you say 32 bit subsystem actually removed from Core version.